# Return values from cross server sprocs

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on server A. Server B is a linked server, the connection is fine and permissions are all good. The last line of the proc on server A uses EXEC to call the proc on server B. I would like if possible to be able to return a value from the proc on server A that is a return value in the proc being called on server B. Is this possible? The code looks something like:

```
proc foo(outputFromB INT OUTPUT)
...
EXEC [someserver].[db].[dbo].[ProcB]
@inputA
@inputB
@outputA
```

I would like the value of output A to be returned from proc foo in outputFromB. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure the *formal* parameter of `ProcB` corresponding to the actual parameter `@outputA` is declared with either `OUT` or `OUTPUT` keyword:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcB (
  other parameters,
  @outputParam type OUTPUT
)
AS
…
```

When invoking the procedure, the same keyword must also be added after the *actual* parameter in order for the new value to be actually assigned to it:

```
proc foo(@outputFromB INT OUTPUT)
...
EXEC [someserver].[db].[dbo].[ProcB]
@inputA
@inputB
@outputFromB OUTPUT
```

You can also see that `foo`'s formal parameter is used directly in the command invoking `ProcB`, which should be perfectly fine if you don't need to process the returned value in any way before assigning it to `@outputFromB`.

So that's it. Just don't forget to supply `OUTPUT` when calling `foo` too.